# WPF: Show Context Menu when Only one cell is selected

Tags: c#, wpf

What is wrong with this code?

The DataTrigger on SelectedCells.Count is not firing up.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Exclude.Exclude,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFEBEBEB"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedCells.Count,ElementName=dgAssets }" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowMenu}" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>                          
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Trying to show the context menu , only when just a single cell is selected.

Comment: Any binding errors in the Debug output?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerdJust checked, no binding errors.

Comment: Can you copy here your whole DataGrid and ViewModel?

Comment: Sure will, do. Need to remove extra info. Will update in couple of hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SelectedCells` property of a `DataGrid` returns an internal object called `SelectedCellsCollection`. It extends another class called [VirtualizedCellInfoCollection](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/VirtualizedCellInfoCollection.cs,d575188b1fa15953). It does not implement neither `INotifyCollectionChanged` nor `INotifyPropertyChanged` interfaces. Moreover its `Count` property is not a dependecy property.

So your binding is not able to notify to your data trigger when the number of selected cells increases or decreases. For the data trigger its value is always 0.

Comment: ah, makes sense, because when I changed the DataTrigger value to 0, all cells were green. Any pointers on how can I hide the Row context menu  when more than one cells are selected.

Comment: @cyboashu this is just an hint: in my opinion you should create your own datagrid (extending the standard one) with a "selected cell count" dependecy property.